# Problems installing Docker for Windows CE

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10

> Unable to stop: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The specified module 'Hyper-V' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
>   at , : line 79
>      at Docker.Backend.HyperV.RunScript(String action, Dictionary`2 parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\HyperV.cs:line 177
>      at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStop() in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 279
>      at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 122
>      at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 47
>      at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 145

I have just download the stable version of Docker for Windows and after installing it I clicked on the icon and opened it, it gave the above error.

I have tried reinstalling it a couple of times, I have tried resetting to factory defaults, I have tried generating the following error code but cant find the solution anywhere, diagnostic-id:B5D6D78B-961A-48B2-AC08-2CEDD9BF5D2D/2017-10-13_18-45-00.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that "Docker for Windows" isn't compatible with Windows 10 Home Edition. It requires Hyper-V which is only available in the Professional & Enterprise Editions. It doesn't clearly warn you about this though.

The solution [according to Docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install) is to use [Docker Toolbox for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/#ready-to-get-started) instead.

Note: when I tried to install Docker Toolbox, I ran into several problems, and I had to uninstall VirtualBox and reinstall the [official version from Oracle](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). It may be worth reading the [Docker Toolbox setup instructions](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/).